# Compiled formula is too big to execute - Reduce Formula Size

Tags: formula, formula-field

I am getting the below error for the below formula code -

```
IF( Risk_Score__c >=3.2,'High',
IF( Risk_Score__c >=0.8 && Risk_Score__c<3.2,'Moderate','Low'
))
```

> Error - Compiled formula is too big to execute (13,642 characters).
>   Maximum size is 5,000 characters

Risk_Score__c is a formula field with below formula -

```
IF(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Always' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Extreme Harm', 16,
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Always' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Very Serious Harm', 8,
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Always' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Serious Harm', 4, 
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Always' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Minor Harm', 2, 
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Always' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='No Significant Harm', 1, 
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Very Likely' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Extreme Harm', 12.8, 
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Very Likely' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Very Serious Harm', 6.4, 
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Very Likely' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Serious Harm', 3.2, 
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Very Likely' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Minor Harm', 1.6, 
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Very Likely' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='No Significant Harm', 0.8,
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Likely' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Extreme Harm',9.6,
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Likely' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Very Serious Harm',4.8,
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Likely' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Serious Harm',2.4,
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Likely' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Minor Harm',1.2,
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Likely' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='No Significant Harm',0.6,
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Infrequent' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Extreme Harm',6.4,
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Infrequent' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Very Serious Harm',3.2,
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Infrequent' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Serious Harm',1.6,
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Infrequent' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Minor Harm',0.8,
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Infrequent' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='No Significant Harm',0.4,
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Remote' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Extreme Harm',3.2,
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Remote' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Very Serious Harm',1.6,
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Remote' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Serious Harm',0.8,
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Remote' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Minor Harm',0.4,
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Remote' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='No Significant Harm',0.2,
0
)))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

[image]

Comment: is Risk_Score__c also a formula field ? can you post the formula of the Risk_Score__c field as well ?

Comment: You would also need to include any formula fields that are used in `Risk_Score__c` as well.

Comment: It is too long to post it. I have written like this below: - IF(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Always' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Extreme Harm', 16,
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Always' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Very Serious Harm', 8,
if(TEXT(Likelihood__c) == 'Always' && TEXT(Impact__c) =='Serious Harm', 4,

Comment: I need to have 30 coimbinations like the above code..

Comment: If you click **edit** on your question you can post it there

Comment: Done--Can u please check.

Comment: Theres only about 1,800 characters in that formula field. It doen't explain how you are getting 13,642 characters. Are `Likelihood__c` and `Impact__c` formula fields as well?

Comment: No Likelihood__c and Impact__c are not formula field..

Comment: compiled size does not have anything to do with actual characters. It can be very different.

Comment: Hi BarCotter. I have added a pic where you can see total char is 3243 for risk score..

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the formula a bit smarter. Looks like there are some fixed factors that you are using in the calculating. Why not do something like this:

```
CASE(TEXT(Likelihood__c),
'Always',1,
'Very Likely',0.8,
etc.......,
0
)
*
CASE(TEXT(Impact__c),
'Extreme Harm',16,
'Very Serious Harm',8,
etc.......,
0
)
```

Also in the result field try to reduce the amount of references to Risk_Score__c. Each reference will again add the complete size of Risk_Score__c to the total. E.g. use CASE there or reduce by 33% by doing 1 less reference:

```
IF( Risk_Score__c >=3.2,'High',
IF( Risk_Score__c <0.8,'Low','Moderate'
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like what is shown below (it is untested), which uses [CASE](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#CASE). This will give you the same output as your formula.

```
CASE(TEXT(Impact__c),
    'Extreme Harm', 3.2,
    'Very Serious Harm', 1.6,
    'Serious Harm', 0.8,
    'Minor Harm', 0.4,
    'No Significant Harm', 0.2,
    0
)
*
CASE(TEXT(Likelihood__c),
    'Remote', 1,
    'Infrequent', 2,
    'Likely', 3,
    'Very Likely, 4,
    'Always', 5,
    0
)
```

From looking at your code I can see that the `Impact__c` produces a set of values and the `Likelihood__c` adds a weight to those values.

For example '**Extreme Harm**' is a value of 3.2. When the `Likelihood__c` changes the value increases:

- 'Remote' = 3.2 x 1 = 3.2
- 'Infrequent' = 3.2 x 2 = 6.4
- 'Likely' = 3.2 x 3 = 9.6
- 'Very Likely = 3.2 x 4 = 12.8
- 'Always' = 3.2 x 5 = 16

Comment: I think they are probably picklist values, so you probably do need to wrap them in Text()

Comment: Hi. I need a combination of Likelihood__c & Impact__c..

Comment: Thanks @CaspNZ I have updated my question. This formula will give the exact same output as yours.